# Manual trans/ high rev in all gears power not transferring HELPPPP!

Tags: manual-transmission, cobalt

Starting at the beginning, I thought I had a bad wheel bearing on the front driver side, once I replaced my wheel hub, sound was still there. Was advised maybe the culprit is a bearing within the transmission? A few days after having replaced the wheel hub assembly, with the previous sound still very much apparent, my tachometer started revealing problems. After about a week and half the issue has grown progressively worse. Regardless of which gear l'm in the tach  shows high and fluctuating rpms, without equivalent power being transferred. At this point unless I baby her in each gear, speed is hard to increase, and accelerating responds as though I'm in neutral.. are these two issues correlated?? And most importantly, what the hell is wrong with my transmission?? Any light shed would be greatly appreciated. I'm beyond frustrated.

Comment: It surely sounds like a bad clutch to me?

Comment: That clutch is slipping, won't be long before you have no drive or an expensive bang...

Comment: Are there any other contributing factors that could add to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Replace your clutch as it is worn out.

The gearbox is fine, if there was a problem with it, it would be either not transferring power at all, or not engaging in gear...